# Unique name for Hazelcast client instances

Tags: hazelcast

I have 3 node hazelcast server cluster and hazelcast client is started in each node. The hazelcast client uses smart routing and client / server mode is used.

I collect the list of clients connected to Hazelcast server cluster via IExecutorService and ClientService.getConnectedClients() in  each Hazelcast client. After fetching the list I want to loop through the fetched list of client and compare it with own instance (the client who fetched the list) and if found perform some application logic. One way to do is to assign a unique name to client during HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient.

Is it possible to have a unique name set to each Hazelcast client instance ? .

Please let me know if I am not clear.

Thanks
JK

Comment: Found that http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html/idgenerator.html there is unique id generator but it returns long.

Comment: try out of the code given below and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can identify a hazelcast client uniquely as follows.

```
HazelcastInstance clientInstance = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
String localUUID = clientInstance.getLocalEndpoint().getUuid();
System.out.println("Client UUID is  : " + localUUIID);
```

In the next step, retrieve the connected clients list using `ExecutorService` --> `ClientService.getConnectedClients` and then iterate over the list as follows.

```
for(com.hazelcast.core.Client client : clients)
{
    if(localUUID.equals(client.getUuid()))
    {
        System.out.println("Found : " + client.getUuid());
        // perform your logic here...
        break;
    }
}
```

There you go !

Comment: Sorry Dinesh. I missed your reply, We handled it using IP address of client as unique identity.

Comment: If IP address is not going to change, then that is also a feasible solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you can wait til Hazelcast 3.6,

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast-client/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/client/config/ClientConfig.java
has
    `public void setInstanceName(String instanceName)`

Comment: Is instanceName going to be set by hazelcast or calling code will have to set it ? From the looks of it, I think caller will have to do it.

Comment: If you don't provide a value as part of config build, Hazelcast will create one as it does currently.

Comment: `HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig).getName()` is not unique as of now. How can that be used in this scenario ?